# using JSTL tags in ajax inside JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, el

I am dealing with Ajax and JSP in how getting data from java (doGET function) to parse them in jquery ajax.
I typed different script code and here is the last one :

**java code :**

```
/**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // ArrayList for retrieving database schemas
        ArrayList<String> databases = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tablesSelectedDB = new ArrayList<String>();

        String selectedDB = null;

        selectedDB = request.getParameter("selectedDB");

        // make a connection to MySQL Server
        getConnection();

        // execute the query via connection object
        try {
            databases = executeMySQLQuery("show databases;", "Database", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            tablesSelectedDB = executeMySQLQuery("show tables from " + selectedDB + ";", "", "Tables_in_" + selectedDB);
            System.out.println(tablesSelectedDB.size());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("databases", databases);
        request.setAttribute("databaseSize", databases.size());
        request.setAttribute("tablesSelectedDB", tablesSelectedDB);
        request.setAttribute("tablesSelectedDBSize", tablesSelectedDB.size());

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Ajax script code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#selectedDB").change(
                        function() {

                            var selectedDB = $("#selectedDB").find(":selected")
                                    .val();

                            if (selectedDB !== "") {

                                $.ajax({
                                    type : 'GET',
                                    data : {
                                        selectedDB : selectedDB,
                                        //tablesSelectedDB : tablesSelectedDB
                                    },
                                    url : 'XLSReader',

                                    beforeSend : function() {

                                    },
                                    success : function() {

                                        var tablesSelectedDB = "${tablesSelectedDBSize}";

                                        window.alert(tablesSelectedDB)

                                        $("#databaseTables").html();
                                        $('#databaseTables').change(
                                                function() {
                                                    var selectedTable = $(
                                                            '#selectedTable').find(
                                                            ":selected").val();
                                                });

                                    },

                                });
                            }
                        });             });
```

let me explain, 
I am displaying all databases that are existed in my MySQL server with HTML

```
<select id="selectedDB">
<c:forEach var="database" items="${databases}">
<option value="${database}">${database}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

and I got them with success, then , when I would like to select one of them , I want to get all the tables of the selected database. 
So I used Ajax Jquery to send the selected database value in the `doGet function` to get its tables.

```
selectedDB = request.getParameter("selectedDB");
        //String selectedDB = "noe";

        // make a connection to MySQL Server
        getConnection();

try {
            tablesSelectedDB = executeMySQLQuery("show tables from " + selectedDB + ";", "", "Tables_in_" + selectedDB);
            System.out.println(tablesSelectedDB.size());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

request.setAttribute("tablesSelectedDB", tablesSelectedDB);
request.setAttribute("tablesSelectedDBSize", tablesSelectedDB.size());
```

the `System.out.println(tablesSelectedDB.size());` prints me the size of the selected database which means it works fine.
so I put `tablesSelectedDBSize` in

```
request.setAttribute("tablesSelectedDB", tablesSelectedDB);
        request.setAttribute("tablesSelectedDBSize", tablesSelectedDB.size());
```

to use it in my JSP file, exactly in success function() of ajax

```
success : function() {
            var tablesSelectedDB = "${tablesSelectedDBSize}";

            window.alert(tablesSelectedDB)

            $("#databaseTables").html();
            $('#databaseTables').change( function() {
                 var selectedTable =   $('#selectedTable').find(":selected").val();
            });

                                    },
```

the `window.alert(tablesSelectedDB)` prints me 0 instead of 10 tables.

Comment: Your EL (`${tablesSelectedDBSize}`) is only evaluated when the page renders, not when any arbitrary JavaScript function is executed. Include the values you want in the AJAX response.

Comment: thank you for your reply , but I didn't get you .. can you explain more than this

Comment: thank you it is very helpfull